# Calendly Web Page Integration render calendar after page load

Tags: javascript, html, calendly

I have a page which must show the Calendar (from Calendly) of a selected person.

I'm struggling to get the Calendly 'Calendar' widget to render when the calendar is changed.

The calandly widget code is:

```
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="calendly_url_goes_here"></div>
```

How do I change the `data-url` in javascript and then make the calendar update/render again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setAttribute` to change the `data-url`

```
clandlyElement.setAttribute('data-url', 'new-value-here');
```